# Unreal Engine 4: How to select value for FName uproperty from array of FNames by dropdown list in editor details?

Tags: unreal-4

I have an actor class which have a FName UPROPERTY and also an array of strings loaded from config. I need to select a value from that array in editor details of that actor and assign it to that property instead of entering that string manually.

I need the same behaviour as UENUM value selection but for FName.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. The solution is very easy

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, meta = (GetOptions = "GetNameOptions"))
FName Name;

UFUNCTION(CallInEditor)
TArray<FString> GetNameOptions() const
{
    return { TEXT("N1"), TEXT("N2"), TEXT("N3") };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I have done this is with a `DetailsView` widget.

In the object you are editing, add a

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
FNameSelector CustomProperty;
```

which will be the custom property exposed in the editor details view. Then define `FNameSelector` and add a custom property for it.

Make a struct to hold the name value:

```
USTRUCT()
struct FNameSelector
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    FName Name;

    FAssetCategoryNameSelector()
    {}

    FAssetCategoryNameSelector(const FName& InName) :
        Name(InName)
    {}
};
```

Make a class with the `IPropertyTypeCustomization` interface, and put your string data in it somehow,

```
class FSomeClass: public IPropertyTypeCustomization
```

In the `PropertySelectionChanged` callback, set `CustomProperty.Name` of your object.

In your module, add a custom property type for your object and the selector class that you just made.

```
Module.RegisterCustomPropertyTypeLayout("NameSelector", FOnGetPropertyTypeCustomizationInstance::CreateStatic(&FSomeClass::MakeInstance));
```

Comment: "In your module" - I don't have a module. It's just a class in my game

Comment: Can you give me a code example of IPropertyTypeCustomization